# Load class from DLL, instantiate it as another class children

Tags: c#, dll

I have class foo

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected int[,] bar;
    public abstract Point test(int a, int b);
}
```

And in program, I have another 4 classes inherited from `foo`.

```
class inheritedClass : Foo
{
// ...
}
```

And I want to load another class from DLL and add it to `List<Foo>`, where I store all classes that are inherited from `Foo`. How can I do it? Now, I have this:

```
try
{
     DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(name);
     Type type = DLL.GetType("DLL.customObject");
     var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     // Even when [obj] is not null, [newObj] is always null
     newObj = obj as Foo;
 }
 catch
 {
     return false;
 }
```

Here's my DLL

```
namespace DLL
{
    public class customObject : Foo
    {
         // ...
    }


    public abstract class Foo
    {
        protected int[,] bar;
        public abstract Point test(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection is particular about the name. Check the `FullName` property on the `Type` info of the `customObject` object you want to load. Also, maybe try a name match, e.g. `DLL.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "customObject");`

Comment: quoting OP: `// Even when [obj] is not null, [newObj] is always null`
if obj is not null, try a `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (obj.GetType());` to understand what is the type of the instance created. Also, be sure that `Dll.customObject`inherits from `foo`

Comment: @BurnsBA the name is correct, `Type type`: `Name="customObject", FullName="DLL.customObject"`

Comment: @GianPaolo `Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` returned `DLL.customObject`. I'm sure, `DLL.customObject` inherits from foo. Cannot the problem be: I have indentical abstract classes `Foo` in both DLL and my program. It's in DLL because I need to inherit it and it threw syntax error. Isn't the problem there? Shouldn't I somehow inherit the `Foo` class from program instead of `Foo` class from DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to make a class from DLL a sublcass of your custom class. It is not possible in C#. If you don't have access to the code of a class you can't change its inheritance hierarchy. Consider using `List<object>` to store your objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And if programmer of the DLL had the original code, can he somehow create DLL that will do what I want? Maybe via referencing the original app?

Comment: Yes, if you have source code of the class, you can inherit any class you want. Check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var assembly= Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\myDll.dll");
// Assembly executingAssembly = assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type type = assembly.GetType("DLL.customObject");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

or

```
Type t = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Hover on t you might get current assemblies that are loaded.

Comment: Here, `Type type` becomes null, `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` does not not contain the class. The DLL I have is in separate file.

Comment: @SoptikHa I have modified the code with just path updated and also another way.

Comment: `t` contains assemblies I have loaded (some system assemblies) and the one assmbly I have loaded by file name. Could you please also look at my comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506691/load-class-from-dll-instantiate-it-as-another-class-children/45506814?noredirect=1#comment77974742_45506691 Maybe there is the problem